# batch file to compare two files in different directories with the same name and then copy newest

Tags: file, batch-file, compare

While I have seen similar questions on this site, none of them seem to me to really be able to do what I need.  I need to compare two files of the same name in different locations.  One is on a computer, the other location is on a flash drive.  The batch file will reside on the flash drive.  I need to compare the two files, then copy the newest one so it is on both the computer and flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

### Lecture

What have you tried or leaned in regards to batch scripting? **[See StackOverflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)**.  Please do not just post questions in need, but show what you have tried and what you have learned.

Here are some great resources to get you going:

**[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)** \
**[DosTips](http://www.dostips.com)** \
**[SS64](http://ss64.com/)** \
**[Rob van de Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php)** \
**[ComputerHope](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/commandi.htm)**

Also, take a look at these commands

`xcopy` or `robocopy`

Type most any command followed by `/?` to see the help documentation.

---

### Answer

```
xcopy "E:\path on flash drive\file.ext" "C:\path on computer\file.ext" /D
xcopy "C:\path on computer\file.ext" "E:\path on flash drive\file.ext" /D
```

Comment: Let's see, I have tried the only two commands I know, FC and Comp, but, I don't know how to get them to indicate which file is different?  Just that there is a difference.  I have tried looking for software that would do this, but, either it will cost me to get it or all it will do is just compare and not provide me with a way to do what I need to have done.  As for using xcopy and robocopy, neither program will compare two files of the same name and move the newest one. Maybe this is not the place for me to look for help on a batch file.

Comment: @ThomasPerry Using the `/D` option will cause the xcopy command to only copy the newest version of the file (based on the file date).  Please actually lookup what these commands do instead of just making assumptions.

The two commands up above do this exactly! "I need to compare the two files, then copy the newest one so it is on both the computer and flash drive."  Do you want it to ask you which one to copy back and forth or be automatic?